# GCC configure error

Tags: gcc, suse, configure

When I'm trying to install GCC for SLED 11 SP3, the terminal show me this error:

```
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile.
```

Before to intall GCC, I installed the GMP (4.3.2), MPFR (2.4.2), MPC (0.8.1).

This is the log message that I got: [configure.log](http://pastebin.com/Rb73FQ2t)

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: May I ask why you aren't using the GCC that comes with SLED?

Comment: You appear to have posted the wrong `config.log` file. `configure` exited without error when producing this one, which it shouldn't have for the error you got. (See "exit 0" at the end of the file.) GCC is built up in stages, so there should be at least one other `config.log` file somewhere. `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc/config.log` is a good bet.

Comment: When I'm trying to install the PCRE (8.35) for the Apache server, it displays me that didn't find a C++ compiler.

Comment: So install the C++ compiler that is part of the SuSE Linux distribution: `sudo zypper in gcc-g++`.